# Linux unity editor : unity-editor depends on npm; however: Package npm is not installed

Tags: node.js, linux, unity-game-engine, npm

I am trying to install the linux unity editor as posted here https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/page-2
I got the latest nodejs package version v9.2.0 I can run the node , npm from console as a root. I added the path for node package to .bashrc file
However during the .deb installation, its failing to detect npm. Please see the log below. Request help on this issue.

```
 root@VirtualMazeLinux:/home/mkandula# dpkg -i ./Downloads/unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb 
 Selecting previously unselected package unity-editor.
 (Reading database ... 189549 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb ...
 Unpacking unity-editor (2017.2.0f3) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of unity-editor:
  unity-editor depends on npm; however:
   Package npm is not installed.

 dpkg: error processing package unity-editor (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
 Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1) ...
 Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
 Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  unity-editor
 root@VirtualMazeLinux:/home/mkandula# node -v
 v9.2.0
 root@VirtualMazeLinux:/home/mkandula# npm -v
 5.5.1
 root@VirtualMazeLinux:/home/mkandula#
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install NodeJS from repository of your distro:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: root@VirtualMazeLinux:/home/mkandula# node -v
 v9.2.0
 root@VirtualMazeLinux:/home/mkandula# npm -v
 5.5.1

Comment: Okay, is the installation falling again?